# Better way to say "take advantage of"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

In the conclusion part of my article, I want to describe the proposed method A is based on methods B and C, literally the combination of B and C: Pros of B and C are taken and cons are avoided.

So can we say: A takes advantages of both B and C, and the limitations in B and C are eliminated/removed?

I believe there is a better way to compose the above sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Best of both worlds](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/best%20of%20both%20worlds)

> Method A is the best of both worlds, taking the advantages of B and C without the [drawbacks](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drawback).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest: "A combines the advantages of both B and C, while avoiding the limitations of each."